# Is there a statement that if returned by a function that is called by another function, it ends the calling function?

Tags: python-3.x

I am programming a betting application consisting of multiple games, each with it's own function. I want to check if the bets for each game is less than or equal to 0. If yes, it prints invalid bet and the game function stops and returns 0 winnings. I want the checker to be a function that I can call for each game instead of including the entire code for each one. Is there a statement, when returned by a function, it ends/returns the calling function?

I did an if statement for each game function but this seems repetitive so I was thinking if I could have it as a function instead.

```py
def roulette(bet):
  if bet <= 0:
    print('Invalid Bet')
    return 0
  # other code

def card_draw(bet):
  if bet <= 0:
    print('Invalid Bet')
    return 0
  # other code

def bet_checker(bet):
  if bet <= 0:
    print('Invalid Bet')
    # statement that returns 0 to the function that calls it

# ideal roulette function

def roulette(bet):
  bet_checker(bet)
  # other code
```

Comment: You could throw an error, that would exit the caller unless caught there. But otherwise, no. You could alternatively return whether the bet was valid, i.e. `if not bet_checker(bet): return`.

Comment: instead of printing invalid bet, why don't you raise an Exception with message invalid bet?

Comment: I couldn't throw an error because it ends the entire script. I want my succeeding game functions to continue if they have a valid bet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you correct. But you could let your `bet_checker` function return False in case the bet is not valid. The calling function `roulette` will only run "other code2" when bet_ckecker returned True.

```
def bet_checker(bet):
    if bet <= 0:
        print('Invalid Bet')
        return False
    else:
        # other code1
        return True

def roulette(bet):
    if bet_checker(bet):
        print('Valid bet')
        # other code2
```

Calling

```
roulette(0)
```

returns 'Invalid Bet' and won't run any other code.